# How can a .NET (CF) DataRow spontaneously set all values to DBNull?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm working with .NET DataSets in the Compact Framework. A single DataSet contains four or five tables with light data-usage (on the order of a few rows each). The primary data table (upon which all the foreign key constraints are based) contains a single row. The DataSet is persisted to disk as an XML file (using DataSet.WriteXML).

What we are finding is that, every so often, the DataRow's values all get set to DBNull for no apparent reason. What's more, when the data gets persisted again, the primary data table's single row gets written with no data.

For example, we would expect to see:

```
<MyDataSet>
<MyTypedDataRow id="1" data1="data" data2="more data" />
...
```

where "data1" and "data2" are non-nullable columns. Instead, we are rarely getting:

```
<MyDataSet>
<MyTypedDataRow />
...
```

which should be impossible.

Our environment does use multi-threading, but access to the DataSet is heavily thread-guarded.

When I attempt to cause this to happen in a debugger, all of my efforts are met with errors due to the table's constraints.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this could be happening?

Thanks for looking.

---

EDIT: One thing I didn't mention which may be a contributing factor. This is a strongly-typed DataSet that was made using a Visual Studio designer, but has undergone significant **manual** modification after creation (don't blame me; it was before my time). Obviously, this could have a bunch of unanticipated side-effects... but I can't see how this issue could be made to happen even if we tried.

Comment: Is your device sleeping between these errors? Maybe it... loses it somehow coming out of sleep. (???)

Comment: No, I don't think that's it (but thanks for the suggestion; at this point, I'm looking for ANY ideas I haven't thought of). Our device runs continuously, and does not go into any kind of sleep. The funny thing is that our app logs clearly show when the dataset is last modified (successfully), and then saved... then 8 seconds later, "InvalidCastException"s are reported when the app tries to access the other data in the same row that was just modified. Despite the thread-guarding we've put in, I'm willing to believe it's a threading issue... but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly bizaare, and I'd imagine something else is likely going on.

To help you test, I'd suggest wiring up some of the event handlers that you can check.

Here is a test class you might be able to use that works for WM5 and CF 2.0.

See what's happening whenever your data is lost.

```
class TestOnly {

  public DataTable Table { get; set; }

  public TestOnly() {
    Table = new DataTable();
    Table.Disposed += new EventHandler(Table_Disposed);
    Table.ColumnChanging += new DataColumnChangeEventHandler(Table_ColumnChanging);
    Table.RowChanging += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Table_RowChanging);
    Table.RowDeleting += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(Table_RowDeleting);
    Table.TableClearing += new DataTableClearEventHandler(Table_TableClearing);
  }

  bool myAct = false;

  void Table_TableClearing(object sender, DataTableClearEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Table {0} clearing. {1}", e.TableName, DateTime.Now);
  }

  void Table_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e) {
    if (!myAct) {
      e.Row.CancelEdit();
      Console.WriteLine("Edit of {0} cancelled. {1}", e.Column.Caption, DateTime.Now);
    }
  }

  void Table_RowChanging(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
    if (!myAct) {
      e.Row.CancelEdit();
      Console.WriteLine("DataRow Action {0} cancelled. {2}", e.Action, DateTime.Now);
    }
  }

  void Table_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e) {
    if (!myAct) {
      e.Row.CancelEdit();
      Console.WriteLine("DataRow Action {0} cancelled. {2}", e.Action, DateTime.Now);
    }
  }

  void Table_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Table Disposed at {0}.", DateTime.Now);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a little more about this problem, that I think will solve my issue.

I created a simple test-app that contains a designer-built strongly-typed DataSet. The application spawns three threads at start-up. Two modify the values in the same column, then read in the value, and repeat ad infintum. The third thread saves the DataSet to disk continually.

Eventually (within the span of several seconds to a minute), the threads bung up the DataSet, so that it throws an exception with the text: "DataTable internal index is corrupted: 5". If I keep swallowing these exceptions, eventually I come to an "InvalidCastException", where the data cannot be read from the row because it is DBNull. When that happens, I can see the entire row is DBNull, even primary keys.

Funny thing about it is that the "WriteXML" method does *not* throw an exception in this state; the file can be saved this way, even though it violates all constraints.

In my actual application, I think that my thread-guarding is not sufficient around this area. I don't know if this is a bug internal to ADO.NET, or just an argument for good thread-guarding around ADO.NET objects. Either way, it's an extremely annoying problem.